# Communicate classes via tkinter's bind method

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm developing a package with GUI using `tkinter`. Now there is a problem when communicating classes via tkinter's bind method. A simple code which represents what I want to do is listed below:

```
import Tkinter as tk

lists = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

class selects():

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.selectwin()

    def selectwin(self):
        """ listbox and scrollbar for selection """
        sb = tk.Scrollbar(self.root)
        lb = tk.Listbox(self.root, relief ='sunken', cursor='hand2')
        sb.config(command=lb.yview)
        sb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        lb.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        lb.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set, selectmode='single')
        for value in lists: lb.insert(tk.END,value)

        lb.bind('<Double-1>',lambda event: self.getvalue())
        self.listbox = lb

    def getvalue(self):
        """ get the selected value """
        value = self.listbox.curselection()
        if value:
            self.root.quit()
            text = self.listbox.get(value)
            self.selectvalue = int(text)

    def returnvalue(self):
        return self.selectvalue


class do():

    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        sl = selects(root)
        # do something... for example, get the value and print value+2, as coded below
        value = sl.returnvalue()
        print value+2

        root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do()
```

class `selects` adopt `Listbox` widget to select a value in `lists` and return the selected value for use via attribute `returnvalue`. However, error is raised when running the above codes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Analysis\Python\fpgui\v2\test2.py", line 47, in <module>
    do()
  File "F:\Analysis\Python\fpgui\v2\test2.py", line 41, in __init__
    value = sl.returnvalue()
  File "F:\Analysis\Python\fpgui\v2\test2.py", line 32, in returnvalue
    return self.selectvalue
AttributeError: selects instance has no attribute 'selectvalue'
```

I think this error can be solved by combining classes `selects` and `do` together as a single class. But in my package, class `selects` will be called by several classes, so it is better to make `selects` as a standalone class. Further, communications between classes like this will be frequently applied in my package. For example, do something after picking some information in `matplotlib` figure using `pick_event`, or update a list in one class after inputting texts in another class using `Entry` widget. So, any suggestion about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `sl.returnvalue()` right after having created `sl`. However, at this point `sl.getvalue()` has never been called, which means that `sl.selectvalue` does not yet exist.

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you should move the call to `root.mainloop()` to right after the creation of `sl` (`sl = selects(root)`). This way, Tk hits the mainloop, which runs until the window is destroyed, which is when the user double-clicks one of the values. Then, `sl.getvalue()` has been run and the program can continue with calling `sl.returnvalue()` without errors.

---

Since you are not actually calling the mainloop in that part of the code, I've altered your code to reflect that and still work as you want it to. A key method in this is `wait_window`, which halts execution in a local event loop until the window is destroyed. I've used [this effbot page on Dialog Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111225121/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) for reference:

```
import Tkinter as tk

lists = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

class selects():

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.selectwin()

    def selectwin(self):
        """ listbox and scrollbar for selection """
        sb = tk.Scrollbar(self.root)
        lb = tk.Listbox(self.root, relief ='sunken', cursor='hand2')
        sb.config(command=lb.yview)
        sb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        lb.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        lb.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set, selectmode='single')
        for value in lists: lb.insert(tk.END,value)

        lb.bind('<Double-1>',lambda event: self.getvalue())
        self.listbox = lb

    def getvalue(self):
        """ get the selected value """
        value = self.listbox.curselection()
        if value:
            self.root.quit()
            text = self.listbox.get(value)
            self.selectvalue = int(text)
            self.root.destroy() # destroy the Toplevel window without needing the Tk mainloop

    def returnvalue(self):
        return self.selectvalue


class do():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.top = tk.Toplevel()
        self.top.transient(master) # Make Toplevel a subwindow ow the root window
        self.top.grab_set() # Make user only able to interacte with the Toplevel as long as its opened
        self.sl = selects(self.top)
        self.top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.sl.getvalue) # use the if value: in getvalue to force selection
        master.wait_window(self.top) # Wait until the Toplevel closes before continuing

        # do something... for example, get the value and print value+2, as coded below
        value = self.sl.returnvalue()
        print value+2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    d = do(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks. +1 for your answer as it solves the problem in present example. But in my package, `root.mainloop()` is called as the background of the whole package and widgets `Listbox` and `Entry` are constructed on `tk.Toplevel()`, not on `tk.Tk()` directly, how can I deal with this situation?

Comment: Ok, do you want it to be like a popup dialog window from which the user has to select something before continuing?

Comment: Yes, this is what I really want to do. And want to deliver the value user selected to other class.

Comment: Alright, see the edit I've made. I think that's what you want.

Comment: Your modification is performed correctly in my package, thanks.